# PyGtk: Widget overflows window

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3, clutter

My Champlain map overflows my GtkWindow as seen on the attached screenshot. I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar problem on the Internet.

I made a GUI in Glade and left one empty panel so I could fill it in, in code, with a `GtkChamplain.Embed` widget to display a map. It worked almost fine until I set the size request of the `Embed` to prevent the map getting swallowed on window resizes.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I didn't want this to happen:

[image: screenshot of the previous problem]

Sure, I can work around this by setting a limit to how small the window can shrink and to how big the left side of the panel can grow. I would just rather do it in the appropriate way by setting the `Embed`'s size request. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to make it right?

Here's my full code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Champlain', '0.12')
gi.require_version('GtkChamplain', '0.12')
gi.require_version('GtkClutter', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GtkClutter, Clutter
GtkClutter.init([])  # Must be initialized before importing those:
from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk, Champlain, GtkChamplain, Pango

class UserInterface:

    def __init__(self):
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file('zahori.glade')

        self.client_list = builder.get_object("client-list")
        self.main_window = builder.get_object("main-window")
        self.main_panel = builder.get_object("main-panel")
        self.client_treeview = builder.get_object("client-treeview")
        self.main_window = builder.get_object("main-window")
        self.status_label = builder.get_object("status-label")

        self.map_embed = GtkChamplain.Embed()
        self.map_embed.set_size_request(550, 300)
        self.main_panel.add(self.map_embed)

        self.main_window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.main_window.show_all()


UserInterface()
Gtk.main()
```

Below you can find my `.glade` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="client-list"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="main-window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Zahori</property>
    <property name="default_width">700</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="main-box">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="main-menu-bar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Archivo</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-new</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save-as</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkSeparatorMenuItem">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Editar</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-cut</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-copy</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-paste</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Ver</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Ay_uda</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkToolbar" id="main-toolbar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkToolButton" id="new-scan-button">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="action_name">new-scan</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">New scan</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <property name="stock_id">gtk-new</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkToolButton" id="open-button">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="action_name">open-file</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Open file</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <property name="stock_id">gtk-open</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkToolButton" id="save-button">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="action_name">save-file</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Save to file</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <property name="stock_id">gtk-save</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPaned" id="main-panel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeView" id="client-treeview">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="model">client-list</property>
                <child internal-child="selection">
                  <object class="GtkTreeSelection"/>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="client-mac">
                    <property name="resizable">True</property>
                    <property name="min_width">200</property>
                    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Device</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="resize">False</property>
                <property name="shrink">False</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="status-bar">
            <property name="height_request">20</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="status-label">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="margin_left">6</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might have posted this too soon. I quickly found the answer when I discovered  the `child_set_property()` method of `GtkContainer`.

By setting...

```
self.main_panel.add(self.map_embed)
self.main_panel.child_set_property(self.map_embed,"resize",False)
self.main_panel.child_set_property(self.map_embed,"shrink",False)
```

My interface started behaving appropriately. Unless required otherwise I'm keeping this Q&A posted here in case someone stumbles upon a similar problem.